# How to get a list of versions between the latest version and some previous version for a specific object

Tags: powershell, amazon-s3, version

I'm currently trying to use AWS Tools for PowerShell (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/index.html) to pull down files from S3.

My question is about how I can get a list of all versions between the latest version and some older version (further on, I will then pull down specific versions of an object to do things with it).

Figuring out the latest version is easy:

```
(Get-S3ObjectMetadata -BucketName $S3Bucket -Key $file_to_import).VersionId
```

Also getting a list of all available versions for an object is easy:

```
(Get-S3Version -BucketName $S3Bucket -Prefix $file_to_import).Versions
```

This gives me something like this:

```
BucketName       Key       IsLatest VersionId
----------       ---       -------- ---------
fake_bucket_name test.file True     JNvMus2dzvwbHTALXOiROE6eYK2CbQkN
fake_bucket_name test.file False    .pLXJQtvTDLn2kGVyzxXLwHo06DM.eOK
fake_bucket_name test.file False    E_Pldt5QUK69Bkqi4Vzea5YElVITu5vW
fake_bucket_name test.file False    qfHFNcyUPwgQX4Vj.YRUyvKR4iC1LHDN
fake_bucket_name test.file False    .Oq9yR3tmY4xeA2sKcbhO5fhbNgTHN_5
fake_bucket_name test.file False    IqkH06Z17rJy9b43WKwbdlQmYTIKnQCi
fake_bucket_name test.file False    zpd4vZJaP9d8sU2MgOBliDZg5g7dpQI3
fake_bucket_name test.file False    aUkj3nf_LHzvF6iJFi6MDP8yN5yZx4s4
fake_bucket_name test.file False    voXfE2Yucyfk3lYQxuEHoF531i27rqiw
fake_bucket_name test.file False    vpHy533Js8gTBwmVF5Gwfx8gzRHJmuGO
fake_bucket_name test.file False    rCLVePiKJ_kG4m99YK6T58OOWPgXYqc6
fake_bucket_name test.file False    PQ5pPgMep3qmAhXnApl792OTzOgtEBJp
fake_bucket_name test.file False    8x84RYnc7S5Do0DOZqSC2L42q06yYoSl
fake_bucket_name test.file False    LbyQxsfN..p6VmJARs3GZ7aF.Mzh_Q9C
fake_bucket_name test.file False    LALPxyI5myYQbnWXv5XSPdnqpDMZp5E8
```

Where I'm stuck right now is how I can get a list only between the latest version and a specific previous version.

Say, I know I need everything that is newer then VersionId *qfHFNcyUPwgQX4Vj.YRUyvKR4iC1LHDN*.

So, I would need a list like this:

```
BucketName       Key       IsLatest VersionId
----------       ---       -------- ---------
fake_bucket_name test.file True     JNvMus2dzvwbHTALXOiROE6eYK2CbQkN
fake_bucket_name test.file False    .pLXJQtvTDLn2kGVyzxXLwHo06DM.eOK
fake_bucket_name test.file False    E_Pldt5QUK69Bkqi4Vzea5YElVITu5vW
```

I tried using the `Get-S3Version` command again, making use of the `KeyMarker` and the `VersionIdMarker`:

```
(Get-S3Version -BucketName $S3Bucket -KeyMarker $file_to_import -VersionIdMarker $last_processed_version -Prefix $file_to_import).Versions
```

But this only gives me all versions *BEFORE* instead of *AFTER* the VersionId I used as VersionIdMarker.

The result looks more like this and is the exact opposite of what is needed:

```
BucketName       Key       IsLatest VersionId
----------       ---       -------- ---------
fake_bucket_name test.file False    .Oq9yR3tmY4xeA2sKcbhO5fhbNgTHN_5
fake_bucket_name test.file False    IqkH06Z17rJy9b43WKwbdlQmYTIKnQCi
fake_bucket_name test.file False    zpd4vZJaP9d8sU2MgOBliDZg5g7dpQI3
fake_bucket_name test.file False    aUkj3nf_LHzvF6iJFi6MDP8yN5yZx4s4
fake_bucket_name test.file False    voXfE2Yucyfk3lYQxuEHoF531i27rqiw
fake_bucket_name test.file False    vpHy533Js8gTBwmVF5Gwfx8gzRHJmuGO
fake_bucket_name test.file False    rCLVePiKJ_kG4m99YK6T58OOWPgXYqc6
fake_bucket_name test.file False    PQ5pPgMep3qmAhXnApl792OTzOgtEBJp
fake_bucket_name test.file False    8x84RYnc7S5Do0DOZqSC2L42q06yYoSl
fake_bucket_name test.file False    LbyQxsfN..p6VmJARs3GZ7aF.Mzh_Q9C
fake_bucket_name test.file False    LALPxyI5myYQbnWXv5XSPdnqpDMZp5E8
```

What is a proper way of getting a list of more recent VersionIds starting with some past VersionId?
Am I just missing something basic?

Comment: Without knowing anything about S3 cmdlets, and sounding a bit clumsy - why not use `Compare-Object` to extract the newer from the opposite?

Comment: Would `(Get-S3Version -BucketName $S3Bucket -Prefix $file_to_import).Versions | Select-Object -First 3` be of any help?

Comment: I kind of did what LotPings suggested, so I got the result I needed. Still, I'm not happy with that approach as it takes some assumptions on the order of the list. Theo, this would assume that I know it will always be the first three, but I don't, it can be anything between 0 and a few thousand versions at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's too late but I ended up using this:

```
Get-S3Object -BucketName "my-bucket" -Region my-region | ForEach-Object {
$key = $_.Key
(Get-S3Version -BucketName "my-bucket" -Region my-region).Versions | Where-Object {$_.Key -eq $key} | Sort-Object LastModified
}
```

This will sort each object by version from latest to oldest. You can increase performance by using -Key "s3-path-to-object" at Get-S3Object